# extra steps after changing storage engine and adding index

Tags: mysql, innodb, optimization, myisam

Someone told me to look into his website for quick optimization; I'm a programmer and i don't have much experience optimizing databases.

I have a php/MySQL site uses the MyISAM storage engine.  It doesn't have any indexes on the columns.

I want to change the engine to innoDB and add indexes to the columns.

Some tables have a couple hundred thousand rows so it's not a very small database.

My question is mostly about the data that already is in the database.  Do I need to do anything after these changes to make the already stored data aware of that ? or make them compatible with these changes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You came to right place. Let's look at an example.

Suppose you have the following MyISAM table:

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.mytable
(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    firstname varchar(20),
    lastname varchar(20),
    straddr varchar(40),
    city varchar(40),
    state char(2),
    primary key (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

You said you want to do two things:

1. Change the table to InnoDB
2. Add an index

For the above table, here is how to convert the table to InnoDB and add an index on names

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ENGINE=InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ADD INDEX name (lastname,firstname);
```

Here is a way to make the table InnoDB, index it, and keep the original as MyISAM

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.mytablenew LIKE mydb.mytable;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytablenew ENGINE=InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytablenew ADD INDEX name (lastname,firstname);
INSERT INTO mydb.mytablenew SELECT * FROM mydb.mytable;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable RENAME mydb.mytableold;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytablenew RENAME mydb.mytable;
```

## CAVEAT

This answer is really an oversimplification of the conversion. There are still other aspects of setting up InnoDB ([Here is a Pictorial Representation of InnoDB's Infrastructure](http://www.scribd.com/doc/31337494/XtraDB-InnoDB-internals-in-drawing)).  Here are a few of my past posts on such configuration due diligence:

- `Feb 12, 2011` : [How do you tune MySQL for a heavy InnoDB workload?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-do-you-tune-mysql-for-a-heavy-innodb-workload/1185#1185)
- `Feb 16, 2011` : [How to safely change MySQL innodb variable 'innodb_log_file_size'?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size/1265#1265)
- `Mar 04, 2011` : [Clarification on MySQL innodb_flush_method variable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/clarification-on-mysql-innodb-flush-method-variable/1575#1575)
- `Apr 14, 2011` : [What are the main differences between InnoDB and MyISAM?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam/2194#2194)
- `Sep 12, 2011` : [Possible to make MySQL use more than one core?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-then-one-core/5670#5670)
- `Feb 22, 2012` : [Ibdata usage and Recommendations?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13614/ibdata-usage-and-recommendations/13638#13638)
- `Apr 01, 2012` : [Is innodb_file_per_table advisable?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15906/is-innodb-file-per-table-advisable/15907#15907)

Comment: thank you , so what you say is i should make a new table with the same columns and innodb engine and add index to it and then transfer data from old table to new table ?

Comment: That would be faster, plus the added bonus of having the backup of the original MyISAM table.

Comment: thanx again , sorry if i'm insisting on this but i want to be sure . if i add an index to a column , it doesn't work/effect/index the data that already is in the table and i have to insert them again ?

Comment: While I have an answer, it would be better if you posted that as a separate question.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39938/do-i-need-to-reenter-the-old-data-fter-adding-index-to-a-table thanx again