# Do I need to reenter old data after adding an index to a table?

Tags: mysql, index, innodb

I want to add index to my tables. Some of my tables already have couple thousand rows.

Do I need to reenter my stored data after adding index to columns (to make them aware of index/so the indexing affect them as well  or it's going to take care of old data itself ?

Comment: No, adding indexes does not remove data from the tables.

Comment: @ypercube sorry i should have been more specific , i've edited my question ... read inside فاث parenthesis

Comment: No, the creation of the index includes the already stored data in the columns of the index. It's going to take care of the old data itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments posted for your question, @ypercube is right. It is no. Here is why in terms of Storage Engine under `/var/lib/mysql` (default `datadir`):

## InnoDB ([innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) enabled)

With [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) enabled, table data and its indexes live in the database folder next to the `.frm` file. For example, for the table `mydb.mytable`, the manifestation of that InnoDB table outside of `ibdata1` would be:

- `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.frm`
- `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.ibd`

## InnoDB ([innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) disabled)

With [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) enabled, table data and its indexes live in the system tablespace file better known `ibdata1`. The data pages and index pages are 16KB blocks where rows and TEXT/BLOB overflow are managed.

## MyISAM

For the MyISAM `mydb.mytable`, three files comprise its logical presence

- `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.frm` is table structure header
- `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.MYD` holds the data only
- `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytable.MYI` holds the indexes (BTREE, FULLTEXT)

## EPILOGUE

Regardless of Storage Engine, data pages and index pages are separate and distinct entities. Under the hood, when you issue the command

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ADD INDEX new_index (col1,col2);
```

a complete copy of the data is made. That complete copy is scanned and all index pages are migrated along with new index pages for the `new_index` index.