# Where does mysql store data?

Tags: mysql

Where does mysql store data? I found out (by using mysql>SELECT @@datadir ) that it's in var/lib/mysql - but that can't be it. I have a quite big database (4 GB) called 'bot', but all the files in the 'bot' subdirectory (var/lib/mysql/bot) have only 280KB. Where is the rest?

One more thing - 99% of the database's size is a text column in one of the tables - I know that mysql stores it in separate files, but does it create one file per record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using InnoDB and have a reasonably default configuration, tablespace data is in the `ibdata` files, you should have at least `ibdata1` by default.

You may want to read up about its configuration:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-configuration.html

Specifically splitting it so that each table gets its own ibdata file:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html

And there are some related questions:

[Ibdata usage and Recommendations?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13614/ibdata-usage-and-recommendations)

If you're not using InnoDB, disregard that :)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it's innodb. That's actually quite scary that all the databases are stored in a single file... I'll certainly set innodb-file-per-table to true. Thanks again.

Comment: @Konrad: that's actually pretty common. Oracle and SQL Server also store everything in a single file (although you _can_ configure them differently)